# How we get a session key from an access_token

Tags: python, facebook

I got an access_token using facebook Graph API. https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=...
I want session key. is there any method to get session key from access_token?.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such term infinite session keys. But you can ask user to give you offline access extended permission. If user approved the permission, then you can save the session key and later user.

If you use new php sdk, then you'll find there is a method $facebook->setSession($session); You've to pass users's stored session to here.